# PUTMAPPING JAVA SPRING BOOT MONGODB REST API - update not working but creating a new entry

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, microservices, rest

when trying to update an existing entry in mongo db table, using PostMapping and PUT request, everytime i try to update a new entry is created in the table..

The following is my code
controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/expenses")
public class mydataExpController {

@PutMapping("/")
    public mydataExpense updExpenses(@RequestBody mydataExpense exp){
        return expenseServices.updData(exp);
        
}
```

service

```
@Service
public class ExpenseServices {
    @Autowired
    mydataExpRepository mydataexprepository;

public mydataExpense updData(mydataExpense exp) {
        return mydataexprepository.save(exp);
    }
```

repository

```
@Repository
public interface mydataExpRepository extends MongoRepository<mydataExpense, String> {
    

}
```

In postman

```
connection →keep-alive
content-type →application/json
date →Tue, 29 Dec 2020 10:54:51 GMT
keep-alive →timeout=60
transfer-encoding →chunked
```

everytime i execute http://localhost:8080/expenses/ with PUT

a new entry is created in the database

Comment: can you add an example content? Most likely you are not passing id field correctly.

Comment: Please see the content that is passed and the response

Comment: {
 "_id": "5fedba90e11a563ce37e9890",
    "expdate": "12-24-2020",
    "exptyp": "Biriyani Hub",
    "expamt": 0
}

Comment: {
    "expdate": "12-24-2020",
    "exptyp": "Biriyani Hub",
    "expamt": 0
}

Answer (score 2):

I think it creates a new object, because you are just passing it right to the repo.save().

First you should find an existing myDataExpense, and modify/update it, and then call the repository.save().

Fyi you also could do something like this with mongoTemplate.

```
Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("<id attribute name of your myDataExpense Document>").is(exp.getId);
Update update = new Update().set(".....$", exp);
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, myDataExpense.class);
```